# Generating XML in C# ( using a class generated from XSD)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am trying to generate an `.xml` file using C#. I am using a class generated from an XSD for this purpose.

To be precise I am doing some experiment with [Nunit `results.xsd`](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.2/files/Results.xsd).

I need to generate some elements multiple times. I have below code at end of each function

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(resultType));
  using (var stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml",true))
serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

When I execute this multiple times, I am seeing the `xml` tag with XML version and encoding getting appended every time.

How can I put them as a individual functions so that I can call the objects  multiple times for creating multiple XML elements of same type and in the end save the XML with data? I need the generated file to have structure similar to Nunit's results XML file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Also not sure I understand the question.  A valid XML file must have a single [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), so you could save your results as a `List<resultType>`, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: @dbc
xml has a valid root element. But the element underneath it can be of 1 or more occurences. I need a way to have as many elements as program need and then save the xml.
This is what i meant. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit;
We use a "proxy" class to change the outcome without altering the existing schemes.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Tool.Cons
{
class Result
{
    [XmlElement("test-suite")]
    public testsuiteType[] testsuite { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public decimal total { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public decimal failures { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute("not-run")]
    public decimal notrun { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string date { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string time { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void AppendTestSuite(XDocument xdocument, testsuiteType suite)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(testsuiteType));
        using (var writer = xdocument.Root.CreateWriter())
        {
            // We need this for some reason...
            writer.WriteWhitespace("");
            ser.Serialize(writer, suite);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var res = GetTestResult();
        var xdoc = new XDocument();
        // Create the root element.
        using (var writer = xdoc.CreateWriter())           
            ser.Serialize(writer, res);

        // For testing purposes:
        AppendTestSuite(xdoc, res.testsuite);
        var _out = xdoc.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

---

You could run xsd.exe (In the Microsoft SDK folder) using the switch `/c <path to xsd>` to generate a strongly-typed class for you. It's perfect in quite some cases. However!! The structure that is created isn't your daily class building experience. The class is quite oddly build, so please pay attention when using it.

Comment: Hi,  
Sorry if the question was confusing. I ran xsd.exe and generated a class file.
Now using that class i want to populate data in xml using c#.

Comment: Use XmlSerializer for that. When initialising the XmlSerializer use "typeof(YourXsdClass)" as its parameter and call Serialize the instance. Or deserialise respectively.

Comment: Yes i tried using XmlSerializer. But xml version = 1.0 encoding =utf-8 " is getting encoded for each insertion  .We are supposed to instantiate root element class right.There are many classes including partial classes in Nunit xsd.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you're running multiple tests and want to output all of those tests into one output xml file?

Comment: Yes exactly. Multiple tests will be run and each tests will be having multiple steps.

Comment: This is the structure of an result xml.First braces indicates Class and second braces indicates possible repetition of that element.
.        
test-results (resultType) ( One - root)     
  -> test-suiteType(testsuiteType) (1)     
       ->resultsType    
         ->Items       
          ->test-suiteType(testsuiteType) (Multiple)     
          ->test-case(testcaseType) ( Multiple)     
               ->Categories     
               ->Item(Multiple)     
                  ->failureType and reasonType

Comment: Please review the edit. If you want to go in depth then you will have to add "proxy" classes, like in the example. The way doing this is merely the same.

Comment: Thanks for the proxy class. I have one doubt.

public partial class resultsType {    
    
    private object[] itemsField;    
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("test-case", typeof(testcaseType))]                     
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("test-suite", typeof(testsuiteType))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
How do i add a object of testcasetype and testsuitetype to resultstype?

Comment: i tried like
  resultsType firstTcRT = new resultsType();
testcaseType tc = new testcaseType();

 firstTcRT.Items[0] = tc;
I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Due to soem reason code formatting is not happening. :(

Comment: Never Mind @MusicDemon. I figured out answer for the above query where i was getting Nullreference error. :)

Comment: Good to hear you found the answer. Did my reply answer your question?

Comment: Yes partially. I didnt used proxy class. But i took the idea and used the idea on class which was generated. Thanks for the help.
I have one more query. Can you take a look at that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709198/programatically-generating-objects-for-xml-tag-decorated-with-typeofclass-in-c